# What is the probability the student is not a foreigner, and that if we choose any foreign student he is male

Tags: probability

In one class 30% are females of which 10% are foreigners, while males 15% are foreigners. What is probability:

$a)$ the student is not a foreigner

$b)$ that if we choose any foreign student he is male

Thanks for your attention and your help

Comment: What are you having a problem with?

Comment: I didnt know how to solve

Comment: Where did the problem come from? Surely there is some relevant background you are aware of?

Comment: This problem and many others are the book from which I have begun to solve many examples, but this and the other 2 examples in this chapter cannot

Comment: Suppose that the class has 100 people. How many of them are not foreigners? How many of the foreigners are male? (I hope that the numbers won't become fractional).

Comment: Also, what have you learned so far? Do you know the law of total probability? Bayes' Theorem? Please edit your post with some details about what assistance you need. We do not have your book and cannot see what information you have available to you.

Comment: Write down the formula for what you do know. Let $F$ the set of females, $M$ the set of males and $X$ be the set of foreigners.

Comment: Yes I know  the law of total probability and  Bayes' Theorem

Comment: I think I should use it Bayes' Theorem, but i didnt know how to it

Comment: the biggest help so far has given me is @copper.hat, hope that it will help me to continue

Comment: P(F)=30%, P(M)=70%, P(M|X)=15%, P(F|X)=10%, how to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $P[B] >0$ then $P[A | B] = { P[ A \cap B] \over P[B]}$.

You know that $P[F] = 0.3$ from which you can get $P[M]$ assuming everyone is male or female.

You know that $P[X|F] = 0.1$ and $P[X|M] = 0.15$.

Since $P[X|F] = { P[X \cap F] \over P[F]}$ and similarly for $P[X|M]$ we can compute $P[X \cap F] $ and $P[X \cap M]$ and so we can compute $P[X]$.

a) From this you can compute $P[X^c]$.

b) You can also compute $P[M|X] = { P[M \cap X] \over P[M] }$.

Comment: Thanks sir for your help

Comment: Let me just check that I read the question correctly.

Comment: b) $P[M|X]=\frac{P(X|M)\cdot P(M)}{P(X)}$ or not, and do not undersandt a)

Comment: I made a mistake in interpreting the question, I believe. I will edit. Please unnaccept the answer.

Comment: It is always true that $P[A]+P[A^c] = 1$.

Comment: Finally a) $P[X^c]=1-0.25=0.75,$ and b) $P[M|X]=\frac{0,105}{0,7}=0,15$ i think that the correct result

Comment: Perhaps, I would not trust my arithmetic :-).

Comment: thank you very much from the heart

Comment: why should we use any formula for case b) when we have it in the text of the example, or if you do not understand it properly, ie. after we have selected a foreign student in any way that male

Comment: I don't understand your question. b) asks what is the probability that the student is male given that they are a foreigner which is $P[M|X]$.

Comment: if we select a foreign student in any way, what is the probability of that student being a male

Comment: so the question is here in the book, but why should this requirement be if the solution is given

Comment: think you've worked well, but apparently not good, which was requested when the solution was given

Comment: Are you asking what are the chances that if you pick someone that the will be foreign and male $P[M \cap X]$ or the probability that someone is male **given** that they are foreign?

Comment: that someone is male given that they are foreign

Comment: do you have to change something

Comment: sir help me, that someone is male given that they are foreign

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. I believe that what I have written is the correct answer.

Comment: does something change if the request is, that someone is male given that they are foreign

Comment: We seem to be stuck in an infinite loop. I can answer the same question again, but quickly tire of doing so.